# Node.js socket.io server stops with no warnings or messages?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have socket.io server running on node.js.
No big deal, it's just a simple server that receives and send messages to the client.

```
server.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

So in my console, I get "Listening on port 3000" and everything works fine.
After a certain amount of time I get back into my site and nothing works, the server seems to stop receiving and sending the messages, but in the console is still "Listening on pot 3000".
Then I stop and start it again and everything works again. I couldn't keep track of how much time it takes to stop, or even if it's a fixed amount.

What can I do?

Comment: You mean like echo server? Show us full code, perhaps there's something  there that blocks it.

Comment: It's for a kind of betting site(not sure if I can put the link for the site) and there's too much lines of code for me to paste here. But I use these modules:

`var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var sanitizer = require('sanitizer');
var request = require("request");`

And it has a chat, and a roullete.

Comment: You need more than that, we need to see what you've actually asked Socket.io to do.

Comment: What should I do then? There are hundreds of lines of code. Should I make a brief explanation of what the server does?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look into npm forever. It is an npm package that reboots your server no matter what. You can even kill the process and it will immediately start back up until you specify you want the module to stop your server.

Here is the documentation. I believe it will solve your problem.

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, but the server is still running actually when this happens. But I'll try that anyways, unfortunately if the problem happens again will be in x hours, so I can't tell if this works right away

Comment: There is more documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever that gives you the commands you can use in your js files as well. From what I'm seeing you could easily set it up to have your server restarted on x increment as well (just before it errors) automatically to keep your server persistent and refreshed on a schedule.